# How to align row elements by the baseline in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, android-layout, kotlin, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-compose

How to align elements inside a `Row` by the baseline. My issue is that I want to have a `Row` element with multiple `Text` elements and each of the `Text` elements will have different font and size. By default, they are aligned on the top. I need them to be aligned on the bottom. This is the code:

```kotlin
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity()  {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?)  {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        setContent {
            MaterialTheme {
                Row {
                    Text(
                        text = "Abrakadabra",
                        style = TextStyle(fontSize = 22.sp, fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold)
                    )
                    Text(
                        text = "Abrakadabra",
                        style = TextStyle(fontSize = 14.sp, fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold)
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the rendered view of the code:

[image]

Answer (score 81, accepted):

In Jetpack Compose `1.0.0` it can be done in this way:

```kotlin
Row {
    Text(
        text = "One",
        fontSize = 20.sp,
        modifier = Modifier.alignByBaseline()
    )

    Text(
        text = "Two",
        fontSize = 12.sp,
        modifier = Modifier.alignByBaseline()
    )
}
```

Result:

[image]

---

If someone wants to align text to the last baseline when using multiline `Text` it can be done by using `Modifier.alignBy(LastBaseline)`

```kotlin
Row {
    Text(
        text = "Line 1\nLine 2",
        fontSize = 20.sp,
        modifier = Modifier.alignBy(LastBaseline)
    )

    Text(
        text = "Line 3",
        fontSize = 12.sp,
        modifier = Modifier.alignBy(LastBaseline)
    )
}
```

[image]

Comment: Can you help me with this? @iknow https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70975294/how-to-align-in-compose-row-with-column

Comment: @StuartDTO I was looking at this question but currently I have no idea how to solve this

Answer (score 1):

I'm not at all proud of this; I'm just reporting. The answers listed on stackoverflow ( use `Modifier.alignBy(LastBaseline)`, wrap Text() inside of a Box() and use `Modifier.align(Alignment.BottomStart)`) didn't work for me. Probably because I'm using an `onTextLayout` callback.

Until I can find something way less hacky, this will get me what I want.

```
@Composable
fun ForceTextToBottom(){
    val density=LocalDensity.current
    var offset by remember{mutableStateOf(0.dp)}
    var aHeightThatIAlreadyKnowInAdvance=100.dp
    Column{
           //some stuff before the stubborn Text()
        Row{//the parent of the stubborn Text()
            Image{//the sibling of the stubborn Text()
            Text(sentence, //This is the stubborn Text()
                ...
                ...
                modifier=Modifier
                    .height(aHeightThatIAlreadyKnowInAdvance)
                    .offset(y=offset)
                ...
                ...
                onTextLayout={textLayoutResult->
                    //Some layout size correction logic
                    offset=with(density){100.dp-textLayoutResult.getLineBottom(textLayoutResult.lineCount-1).toDp()}
                    }
                )
            }               
        }
    }
}
```

Not anything I'm happy about. But it gets the text to align to the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following modifier to both the Text composables and that should take care of it. Here is the code for your reference

```
Text(...,  modifier = LayoutGravity.RelativeToSiblings(alignmentLine = FirstBaseline))
Text(...,  modifier = LayoutGravity.RelativeToSiblings(alignmentLine = FirstBaseline))
```

**Screenshot**
[image]

Comment: Thank you, I didn't find anything like this in the docs, can you share the link to this, please

Comment: This was from a lot of experimentation as I was playing with Compose and reading through the code. Dive into the comments for `LayoutGravity.RelativeToSiblings` to get some more info! Unfortunately that's the only resource available at the moment.

Comment: This is no longer valid

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE:  This is no longer valid. Check [@iknow's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60405430/how-to-align-row-elements-by-the-baseline-in-jetpack-compose/65073067#65073067) instead.**

Currently, using Jetpack Compose `1.0.0-alpha03`, you can achieve that with:

```
Text(modifier = Modifier.alignWithSiblings(FirstBaseline), ...)
```