# How to align in Compose row with column

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-compose-text

I have a `Row` with some text and different sizes, then in the end of the `Row` I have a `Column` where I have two `Text` so the output is something like this :

[image]

Perhaps the image is not the best one but as you can see there's a `Row` where I have two `Text` one with different size, and in the end I have a `Column` with two `Text` the problem I'm having is that if I use `Column(modifier = Modifier.alignBy(LastBaseline))` it solves one problem that I was having, but creating a new one that is that is moving all the `Column` to the top, so what I'm looking for is without losing this `Baseline` (since I have different size this command works perfect to avoid playing with margin) I want to avoid moving this column, note that the first `Text` of the `Column` the best is that should have a `alignTopToTop="secondText"` but I don't know if it's possible.

There's the two options, one is if I add the `alignBy(LastBaseline)` make the column fixed and don't move anything just align the `Text` from the bottom and another one is, somehow add this constraint to the second `Text` of the `Row` to don't move the `Column`

My code

```
ConstraintLayout {
            val (text1, text2) = createRefs()
            Column(
                horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
                modifier = Modifier.constrainAs(text1) {
                    top.linkTo(parent.top)
                    start.linkTo(parent.start)
                    end.linkTo(parent.end)
                    bottom.linkTo(parent.bottom)
                }
            ) {
                Text(
                    text = "Hello",
                    style = TextStyle(
                        fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold,
                        fontSize = 12.sp,
                        lineHeight = 18.sp,
                        color = Black,
                    ),
                )
                Row(verticalAlignment = Alignment.Bottom) {
                    Text(
                        text = "World",
                        style = TextStyle(
                            fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold,
                            fontSize = 12.sp,
                            lineHeight = 18.sp,
                            color = Black,
                        ),
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .alignByBaseline()
                    )
                    Text(
                        text = "WORLD",
                        style = TextStyle(
                            fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold,
                            fontSize = 24.sp,
                            lineHeight = 18.sp,
                            color = Black,
                        ),
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .alignByBaseline()
                    )
                    Column(modifier = Modifier.alignBy(LastBaseline)) {
                        Text(
                            text = "^",
                            style = TextStyle(
                                fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold,
                                fontSize = 12.sp,
                                lineHeight = 18.sp,
                                color = Black,
                            ),
                        )
                        Text(
                            text = "^",
                            style = TextStyle(
                                fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold,
                                fontSize = 12.sp,
                                lineHeight = 18.sp,
                                color = Black,
                            ),
                        )

                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

The problem as you can see here
[image]
Is that when I do the `modifier = Modifier.alignBy(LastBaseline)` the column goes up and it makes to make this extra space between the text 2 and text 1, is there any way to avoid this column moving up?

Comment: Kindly provide a minimal reproducible example - https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I think this problem can be solved using [constraint layout](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/layouts/constraintlayout?authuser=1)

Comment: @Abhimanyu updated the question with a reproducible example + screenshot

Comment: @PierreVieira could you take a look to my code and try to help me please?

Comment: @PierreVieira can you help me with ConstraintLayout?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71502444/compose-two-composables-overlaped-and-constraint-with-them